# After uninstall Tridion, SDL Web Content Distributor Transport Service not removed

Tags: web8.5, content-manager, sdl-tridion, razormediator

We have installed SDL web 8.5 publisher  on  separate server, as some of services are not starting due to missing configurations, we uninstalled SDL web 8.5 using .exe. After that when we verified the services, "SDL Web Content Distributor Transport Service" not removed.

Same time when we try to remove razor mediator, it throws below error.

> There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program
>   required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your
>   support personnel or package vendor.

Can you please help me to uninstall SDL web 8.5?

Comment: Did you restart the server? Installers sometimes fail if there is already a pending restart from a previous installation. Try restarting the server and run the installer again.

Comment: Yes Chris we restarted the server, after that also error coming, sdl suggested to use sc.exe tool to remove pending services, still issue repeated.

Comment: After uninstalling sdl web 8.5 the com+ show red down button on My Computer and clicking on com+ shows error. Does anyone know how to resolve this red down button issue?